Restart Python interpreter from code on Databricks Notebook
I added the folllowing code to my databricks notebook
%pip install optree
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

and get the following error message
Note: you may need to restart the kernel using
 dbutils.library.restartPython() to use updated packages.

I already read through the following Stackoverflow Restart Python interpreter from code on Databricks?
and tried all solution but still get the same error message and I am not sure how to fix it

Found the answer by myself -  Inserting dbutils.library.restartPython()
